# MacBook Pro 2018 displaying folder with question mark after SSD erase

Tags: macos, error, internet-recovery

It all started when my MacBook Pro 2018 Touch Bar started restarting randomly due to a kernel panic so I decided the best way to go about it was to remove my Windows partition and update to the latest OS Sonoma, hoping the issue would get fixed. While updating my macOS, for some reason it landed me into an infinite boot loop stuck in the Apple logo with the progress bar then restart.

I searched online and I saw that I should get another MacBook Pro non-Touch Bar and do a T2 fix with Apple Configurator. Revive didn’t work, still was in the boot loop, so I decided to hit restore.

Now, I am faced with the issue of the blinking folder with a question mark. Tried going into Internet Recovery (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>), and it either restarts when the globe is spinning or restarts when I am in Disk Utility.
I also tried using a bootable USB to install Ventura but when I click the USB image it leads me to Internet Recovery.

I am stuck and don’t know what to do. I recently tried erasing my Apple SSD under Disk Utility to AFPS. Still the same issue. I also get the error, “The recovery server could not be contacted” in Disk Utility, then I hear the Apple chime, then the MacBook restarts and shows the folder or spinning globe with a mark.